# Why will Javascript work in certain locations of the page but not others

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just tried implementing a piece of javascript to my wordpress theme and when I placed it above the content in the header the desired effect wasn't working but once I placed it below the content it worked fine.

Why is this? I"m assuming because it could be conflicting with other JS but how do I troubleshot an issue like this for the future?

Comment: Chances are either your javascript is not waiting for the document to load, or it is relying on a library such as jQuery which may not be included until the footer area. Without a link to the page we can only guess.

Comment: @flauntster I have Jquery being loaded in the header, a link to the page is http://stormable.com/hero-lore-demon-hunter/ the effect I was using it for is at the bottom of the post right above related posts you'll see a link called "illidan" I'm working on a tooltip for it and I have JS that allows the tooltip to follow the mouse.

Comment: If the content is a prerequisite for some code to work, it's obvious that for this reason running that code above the content will not work :)

Comment: Although shouldn't once the page is fully loaded everything work properly which it doesn't. And I've always have been accustomed to putting my JS right above the HTML that is using it.

Comment: i can see the tooltip code in your header, and it's not waiting for document load before running. put it inside this - $(document).ready(function(){ ..code here.. });

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are not using the parent function in which all the JavaScript function will reside.

For example you are writing "$('#btn1').click" directly, you need to use On body load function which will wrap up your JavaScript function.

I we doesn't use the Parent function or the wrapper then the code will get executed only when it's applied at the body section, if you try to apply it from head section then it will not work, for this use the bodyOnLoad().